# Are empty accounts automatically undelegated?

Tags: delegation

When a delegated account is drained, is it automatically undelegated and how is the  undelegation operation paid for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fully drain a delegated account. Delegated accounts must have at least 1 mutez remaining in it. You must undelegate first in order to fully drain.

It also actually costs more to fully drain an account, than to leave 1 mutez in it. Most wallets will deduct 1 mutez from any "max send" style function as its cheaper and more efficient

Comment: So there's currently an incentive to not have the account garbage collected which doesn't seem useful. Maybe we need a new drain + undelegate operation that would cost 1 mutez.

Comment: @RichardAyotte pretty much yeah. Last time I checked this (which was well over a year ago, things may have changed), an undelegated account was charged an extra 3 or 4 mutez to send everything, versus max-1 mutez. Since it costs more, everyone just opts to leave 1 mutez. I don't have an answer as to why, I just know thats the way it is/was